# SDK is not proposed to install while installing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

When I am installing Android studio (the latest version that's available at the official website), there isn’t SDK among components to be installed.

[image: scr01]

So, I install what is available, run Android studio, and I am asked to install the SDK anyway. I download the SDK from the official site, unzip it. In Android Studio I choose the unzipped folder as the SDK location, but the app still can’t find the SDK there.

[image: scr02]

What did I do wrong? Are there other options to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Android SDK is not fully installed. Press next and continue the installation. It will download the latest platform API (probably android 8) and other stuff.

Comment: this doesn't help( after a click on next I can run the Studio, but it always asks for  SDK location (

Comment: start the Studio and then download the SDK from Settings

Comment: Thanks, but actually my issue was in proxy settings) Set them to match with my network proxy settings and now everything works.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and mark that as accepted answer. Hopefully, it will help others with the same issue in future :)

Comment: As you said,  Set them to match with my network proxy settings and now everything works. Can you please help me out in details how do we set and what we need to set in proxy settings. I have the same issue as you posted.